# How can I determine which fallback font is being used for a given character?

Tags: x11, fonts, fontconfig, right-to-left

I'm using LibreOffice (7.4.1.2) on Devuan (Daedalus). I've set the right-to-left language group font to some font, let's say it's font family Foo in size 12, regular; and I type a few glyphs in Hebrew or in Arabic. Problem is, this Foo font has no glyphs of Hebrew or Arabic characters. So, I do see some glyphs appearing... my question is: How can I determine which fallback font these glyphs are taken from?

Any reasonable method would do, either using a GUI tool or the command-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First determine the UTF-16 index of your glyph. You can use [this website](https://unicodeplus.com/), where you paste the character and the code is looked up for you.

For example, Let's take the Hebrew letter א (Aleph); it has [Unicode code point 0x5D0](https://unicodeplus.com/U+05D0).

Now, in a shell session, run:

```
fc-match :charset=5D0
```

and you should the font used for your character, and the font variant, e.g.:

```
$ fc-match :charset=5D0 
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
```